# useState does not update the state within .catch after dispatching of asynk thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

In the following code `setError` does not update `error` in the catch after async thunk from redux-toolkit.

```
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const handleLogin = () => {
    dispatch(userLogin({ email, password }))
      .unwrap()
      .then(() => {
        if (userInfo) {
          navigate("/profile");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err) // does not work
      });
  };
```

```
<button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
```

```
export const userLogin = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/login",
  async ({ email, password }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await userLoginRequest(email, password);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(ERR_USER_LOGIN); 
      // ERR_USER_LOGIN is just a constant string from another file
    }
  }
);
```

I know that `useState` does not apply changed immediatly but in my case it ignores changes at all. I suppose that the problem can be related to the scope or something like this. So I've tried to use additional callback which I sent as a parameter and change the state through it but it also does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `userLogin` function actually has caught the error, making `handleLogin` catch not catch anything.
You can throw the error within `userLogin`, so `handleLogin` can catch the error by itself.

```js
export const userLogin = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/login",
  async ({ email, password }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await userLoginRequest(email, password);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(ERR_USER_LOGIN); 
      // Add this
      throw error;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. The problem is, that I definetely go into the `catch` of `handleLogin` because if I print `err` in the console I see it. And also I see that `setErr` is not empty, but still it does not update the state

Comment: @asd Can you provide a code sample on stackbliz?

Comment: sorry for delay. I've uploaded the simplified version of my problem at stackblitz, but everything works there. It seems the problem is a bit more complicated than I expect. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fcfsna?file=src/App.js